# No dx in android SDK?

Tags: android, dx

I just downloaded android SDK for linux_x86.
I cannot find dx though. Document says it should be on /tools/ .
is dx not included any more from some point?

Comment: Have you tried looking in [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.tools/dx/1.7)?

Answer (score 1):

`dx` is specific to the SDK version.

For instance, `./platforms/android-7/tools/dx` in the SDK.